# Setting the "root" of a published npm project

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm publishing an npm package named `foo` to the npm registry.
I wrote the package using a compile-to-js language.
For sanity, I put the compiled output into the `dist/` folder of the project directory.
My `package.json` lists the entrypoint as `dist/entry.js`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "main": "dist/entry.js",
}
```

Sometimes, I want to use files within the package that are not part of the entry point. For example, there is a very useful export called `whatever` inside of `dist/util.js`:

```
import { whatever } from "foo/dist/util";
```

This works, but forcing the users of my package to type `dist/` in all `import` statements is inconvenient.

Furthermore, re-exporting every possible util function is not DRY. **I do not want to re-export from the entrypoint**.

Ideally, I would like to import files from `dist/` using the following syntax:

```
import { whatever } from "foo/util"
```

**How do I configure my `package.json` to search for files in the `dist/` folder of my project?**

Comment: I cannot understand what is the problem with re-exporting. If you have a very good util that is not a logical part of your library then you should post it as a separate library and use it as dependency. If it is a logical part of your library then it should be shipped together with the library. What's bad in having a single entry point to all your library's API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done.

This is the reason why some packages have entry point file that re-exports all public exports (not everything that resides in `dist` is intended to be used by end user), e.g. `@angular/core`.

And the reason why some packages have unsuitable file structure that is published to NPM registry and favours proper import paths, e.g. `rxjs`.